# Create an event with latitude and longitude

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, latitude-longitude

How can I create a Facebook event in [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) setting latitude and longitude?

I have tried the Graph API Explorer, using a post method to `https://graph.facebook.com/MY_ID/events` and parameters.

All works fine, except for latitude and longitude. I also have tried to create a local page with a valid location and set the `page_id`/location in event's parameters, but that only creates the event assigned to the page.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The latitude and longitude are part of the Venue data on an event, but when you create the event, they need to be top level parameters.. Once the event is created and you query for it using the /{eventid} query, they will show up in the Venue JSON node.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same problem and have found no method of posting event data that results in saving latitude and longitude.  What I have discovered is that after an Event is created editing the event - even with no changes - results in a calculation of the latitude and longitude.  The resulting calculated values are slightly different than those passed in the post so these values are clearly not related the parameters I passed.